# Mysql common ascii character collation

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, collation

I am getting an error like this:

```
COLLATION 'latin1_swedish_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'utf8'
```

Whenever I try to run a particular query. The problem in my case is, that I need this query to be able to run - without modification - against two separate databases, which have a different character collation (one is latin1, the other is utf8).

Since the strings I am trying to match are guaranteed to be basic letters (a-z), I was wondering if there was any way to force the comparison to work irrespective of the specific encoding?

I mean, a A is an A no matter how it is encoded - is there some way to tell mysql to compare the content of the string as letters rather than as whatever binary thing it does internally? I don't even understand why it can't auto-convert collations, since it is quite capable of doing it when explicitly told to.

Comment: Please show us the query.